# Yocto device-tree interrupt on certain pin

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, beagleboneblack, device-tree

I am working on a custom .dts file for my beaglebone cape. I've successfully created a bsp-layer and custom image, everythin is working fine. Now i want to make changes in a device-tree to assign certain pins to their roles. I've used a tool provided by ti (pinmux). 
I am struggling to assign an interrupt to few certain gpio pins.
Let's say i've got this inside my .dtsi:

```
gpio0_pins_default: gpio0_pins_default {
    pinctrl-single,pins = <
        AM33XX_IOPAD(0x820, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE7) /* (U10) gpmc_ad8.gpio0[22] */
        AM33XX_IOPAD(0x824, PIN_INPUT_PULLUP | MUX_MODE7) /* (T10) gpmc_ad9.gpio0[23] */
        AM33XX_IOPAD(0x828, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE7) /* (T11) gpmc_ad10.gpio0[26] */
        AM33XX_IOPAD(0x82c, PIN_INPUT | MUX_MODE7) /* (U12) gpmc_ad11.gpio0[27] */
    >;
};
```

Now, i want to assign an interrupt to pin 27 of gpio0 which is active low. How do i proceed? I've read too many sources providing different information, and got confused hence i'm asking for some advice.

Inside interrupt-controller documentation i've found this, but i dont understand few things.

```
           gpioext: gpio-adnp@41 {
                    compatible = "ad,gpio-adnp";
                    reg = <0x41>;

                    interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
                    interrupts = <160 1>;

                    gpio-controller;
                    #gpio-cells = <1>;

                    interrupt-controller;
                    #interrupt-cells = <2>;

                    nr-gpios = <64>;s
```

Where does reg value 41 some from? So far i've thought this was supposed to be an address of a certain GPIO (ex. reg = <0x4804c00 0x1000>;). I understand interrupt-cells and interrupts declaration. Does nr-gpios = pin number to which I want to assign interrupt to ?

Inside am33xx.file i've found this declaration:

```
gpio0: gpio@44e07000 {
            compatible = "ti,omap4-gpio";
            ti,hwmods = "gpio1";
            gpio-controller;
            #gpio-cells = <2>;
            interrupt-controller;
            #interrupt-cells = <2>;
            reg = <0x44e07000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <96>;
        };
```

But in my understanding it's just a setting for a whole GPIO, correct?

Could anybody be so king and provide me an example of a code for setting up an interrupt for lets say pin 27 and 23 active low?

Thanks in advance
BR

Comment: What do you mean under *I am struggling to assign an interrupt to few certain GPIO pins.*? It doesn't work like this. GPIO can be **used** as an interrupt.

Comment: You question about `reg = <0x41>` has nothing to do with the topic. You chose an example of GPIO I²C expander, which I²C bus address is `0x41`.

Comment: It seems you really need to read a lot before trying all this...

Comment: Yea i probably do need to read. What i meant was, how do i configure a certain pin as an interrupt source?

Comment: You need to refer to it as interrupt from GPIO controller (like in above example `interrupts` property for an expander).